# How to convert JSON data to Tabulator table

Tags: javascript, json, tabulator

I have some JSON data that I need to use in Tabulator table.

Simple example here from tabulator.
http://tabulator.info/docs/4.2/quickstart I have to convert the JSON, but am struggling to find a dynamic solution where, say if I had an extra key with key values, it would still work with tabulator table. Here is my JSON data.

```
{
  "Aspen_Premium": [
    279245, 
    945317, 
    118388
  ], 
  "Brokerage_Upfront": [
    825831, 
    141166, 
    507242
  ], 
  "Brokers": [
    "JLT", 
    "Willis", 
    "BMS"
  ]
}
```

I need to have it in a JavaScript file like this.

```
var tabledata = [
    {id: 1, Aspen_Premium: 279245, Brokerage_Upfront: 825831, Brokers: "JTL"},    
    {id: 2, Brokerage_Upfront: 945317, Brokerage_Upfront: 141166, Brokers: "Willis"},
    {id: 3, Brokers: 118388, Brokerage_Upfront: 507242, Brokers: "BMS"},    
]


var table = new Tabulator("#broker-table", {
    height:205, 
    data:tabledata, 
    layout:"fitColumns", 
    columns:[ 
        {title:"Aspen_Premium", field:"Aspen_Premium", width:150},
        {title:"Brokerage_Upfront", field:"Brokerage_Upfront"},
        {title:"Brokers", field:"Brokers"},

    ],
    rowClick:function(e, row){ //trigger an alert message when the row is clicked
        alert("Row " + row.getData().id + " Clicked!!!!");
    },
});
```

My HTML is simply:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Check 1</title>

<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.2.2/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.2.2/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>

<script   src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"   integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"   integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>


<div id="broker-table"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{{url_for('static',filename='js/checking1.js')}}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm using Python Flask. Hence the link for the javascript file, checking1.js has src="{{url_for('static', filename='js/checking1.js')}}">

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I've been struggling with this for several hours trying to do the conversion from JSON to the above hard coded version.
I tried with a for loop, but kept getting issues.

Example of how I was grabbing my JSON data from http://127.0.0.1:5000/broker_data

```
$.get("/broker_data").then(function(data){

    var columns = Object.keys(data);

    var tabledata = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < data[columns[0]].length; i++){


        tabledata.push({"id": i+1, "Aspen": data[columns[0]][i]})
    } console.log(tabledata);
});
```

The above is not ideal as I have to hardcode the "Aspen" key name.

Comment: Are you still needing additional information or did the answer below help?  If you are still having issues, leave a comment to explain what else you need.

Comment: Hey Jerren, sorry for the late response. I managed to get around my problem by creating the var tabledata structure in Python, then send jsonify it using Flask, but thank you for your answer! Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the part about converting the JSON data, this may help. If

```
var data = {
    'Aspen_Premium':[279245,945317,118388],
    'Brokerage_Upfront':[825831,141166,507242],
    'Brokers':['JLT','Willis','BMS']
};
```

One way to get it into the desired format of:

```
[
    {id: 1, Aspen_Premium: 279245, Brokerage_Upfront: 825831, Brokers: "JTL"},    
    {id: 2, Brokerage_Upfront: 945317, Brokerage_Upfront: 141166, Brokers: "Willis"},
    {id: 3, Brokers: 118388, Brokerage_Upfront: 507242, Brokers: "BMS"},    
]
```

Would be the following javascript:

```
//This gets the length of the array in the first element
var numItems = data[Object.keys(data)[0]].length;

var desiredJSON = [];
for( var itemIndex = 0; itemIndex < numItems; itemIndex++){
  var doc = {};
  doc.id = itemIndex;
  for( dataElemIndex in data) {
    doc[dataElemIndex] = data[dataElemIndex][itemIndex];
  }
  desiredJSON.push(doc);
}
```

After this loop, desiredJSON contains the array of documents you're trying to get.
This code is assuming that all elements in data have the same length array.